# Git Grep Multiple Words on Multiple Lines

Tags: git, git-grep

I want to `git grep` the files which has two pre-specified words (if both exist, i.e. `AND`ing), assume these two words are `word1` and `word2`

I tried

```
git grep -e 'word1' --and -e 'word2'
```

And also I tried

```
git grep 'word1'.*'word2'
```

but both retrieve the results only if `word1` and `word2` are on the same line, and the second one does not retrieve if `word2` comes first in the line, which is something that I don't want.
I want to retrieve the files, even if the two words are not on same line (I am not sure how many lines separates them, and the order is not important; any order should be fetched).
Is this possible ?

Comment: Maybe something like `git grep -l word1 | xargs git grep -l word2`... May need to play around with it more if any of your file names contain whitespace or other oddities...

Answer (score 10):

Searching multi-line with `git-grep` is not possible.

Taken from: http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/bug-git-grep-P-and-multiline-mode-td7613900.html

> Yes, and deliberately so, to avoid having to think about things like
>   "how would a multi-line match interact with 'grep -n'?"
>
> We behave as if we feed each line of the contents one line at a time
>   to the matching engine that is chosen by the -P/-E/-G/-F options, so
>   this limitation is unlikely to change.

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
git grep -l word1 |xargs grep -l word2
```

The `-l` option lists the file name instead of the matching line.

This is necessary to feed them into the second right hand side grep (xargs is a utility piping function)

I'm guessing you'd be happy with `-l` on the right hand side also as otherwise it would show the *lines* which match `word2` with no reference to `word1`.

---

Just seeing @twalberg's comment now which recommends a similar solution.

Which reminds me, if you are having trouble with filenames, you need a few extra arguments:

```
git grep -zl word1 |xargs -0 grep -l word2
```

Comment: or `git grep -zl word1 | xargs -0 git grep -l word2`

Answer (score 0):

Since `git-grep` matches patterns per line, like `grep`, the way to achieve this is by breaking up the problem.

First, find all files with `word1`, in those files, find `word2`.

Basically `git grep -l word1 | xargs git grep word2`.

A more thorough example could be something like

```bash
git grep -z --name-only word1 |
  xargs -0 git grep -z --name-only word2 |
  xargs -0 grep -zPl 'word1.*\n{0,5}.*word2'
```

This finds all files where `word2` follows `word1`, separated by at most 5 lines.