# Git Grep Multiple line Regex

Tags: regex, git, gitlab

I wrote a regex to find any file containing `space` `Word` `[` and here is the regex.

```
^\s+Session\[
```

and I want to use this regex in git grep, 
so I set up a file in my repo that matched the regex and runs it.

here is what I run

```
git grep '^\s+Word\[' -- '*.cs'
```

but it returns nothing. I'm really new to git and regex any reference or suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Try `git grep '^[ \t][ \t]*Word\[' -- '*.cs'` or `git grep '^[[:space:]][[:space:]]*Word\[' -- '*.cs'`

Comment: Or `git grep -E '^\s+Word\[' -- '*.cs'`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use Perl regular expressions syntax with `git grep`. Just add `-P` (perl-regexp) option and it will work.

UPD: for those who comes here to find about multi line patterns to `git grep` (just like me): [Git Grep Multiple Words on Multiple Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304348/git-grep-multiple-words-on-multiple-lines)